# How to do multiple pagination without page not found error in Cakephp

Tags: cakephp, pagination, paginator

I have paginate 2 models (Income,Expanse) in the Student model view page . 
I have really page not found problem with cakephp's pagination.

It have no any problem when the paginate result has only 1 page or the same, but It will error if one has more paginate result than other.

```
for example.
-income has paginate result 1 page and expanse has 1 page. No problem at all.
-income has 10 pages and expanse has 10 pages no problem at all.
-income has 2 pages and expanse has 1 page. income page 2 page not found error.
-income has 5 pages and expanse has 2 pages. income page 3,4,5 page not found error.
-income has 10 pages and expanse has 13 pages. expanse page 11,12,13 page not found error.
```

for example(not real one) , Student's view have income and expense items ,Both are display as pagination.

```
//this is how I config paginator in Student controller.
public $paginate = array(
    'Income' => array (
            'order'=>array('income_id'=>'ASC'),
            'limit'=>10,
            'recursive'=>0  
    ),
    'Expense' => array (
            'order'=>array('expense_id'=>'ASC'),
            'limit'=>10,
            'recursive'=>0,

    )
);


<div class="paging">//this is how I config Income paginator in Student view
    <?php
        echo $this->Paginator->prev('< ' . __('previous'), array('model'=>'Income'), null, array('class' => 'prev disabled'));
        echo $this->Paginator->numbers(array('model'=>'Income','separator' => '','modulus'=>100,'first'=>'หน้าแรก','last'=>'หน้าสุดท้าย'));
        echo $this->Paginator->next(__('next') . ' >', array('model'=>'Income'), null, array('class' => 'next disabled'));
    ?>
    </div>


//this is how I config Expanse paginator in Student view
    <div class="paging">
    <?php
        echo $this->Paginator->prev('< ' . __('previous'), array('model'=>'Expanse'), null, array('class' => 'prev disabled'));
        echo $this->Paginator->numbers(array('model'=>'Expanse','separator' => '','modulus'=>100,'first'=>'หน้าแรก','last'=>'หน้าสุดท้าย'));
        echo $this->Paginator->next(__('next') . ' >', array('model'=>'Expanse'), null, array('class' => 'next disabled'));
    ?>
    </div>
```

Please help me. sorry for my english 
If you have any question , please ask me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes It is possible.....

Step1 : Make paging.ctp in View/Elements/paging.ctp

```
<?php if (!isset($this->Paginator->params['paging'])) {
  return;
}
if (!isset($model) || $this->Paginator->params['paging'][$model]['pageCount'] < 2) {
  return;
}
if (!isset($options)) {
  $options = array();
}
$options['model'] = $model;
$options['url']['model'] = $model;
$this->Paginator->__defaultModel = $model;

?>
<div class="paging">
  <ul class="pagination pull-right">
    <?php
        echo $this->Paginator->prev('<<', array_merge(array('class' => '', 'tag' => 'li'), $options), null, array('class' => 'disabled', 'tag' => 'li'));
        echo $this->Paginator->numbers(am($options,array('tag' => 'li', 'separator' => '', 'currentClass' => 'active', 'currentTag' => 'a')));
        echo $this->Paginator->next('>>', array_merge(array('class' => '', 'tag' => 'li'), $options), null, array('class' => 'disabled', 'tag' => 'li'));
    ?>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Step2: Now add this function to Controllers/AppController

```
public function pageForPagination($model) {
        $page = 1;

        $sameModel = isset($this->request->params['named']['model']) && $this->request->params['named']['model'] == $model;
        $pageInUrl = isset($this->request->params['named']['page']);
        if ($sameModel && $pageInUrl) {
            $page = $this->request->params['named']['page'];
        }

        $this->passedArgs['page'] = $page;
        return $page;
    }
```

Step3: Now in controller action do some conditions so that proper page should be call

```
if (empty($this->request->params['named'])) {
$page = $this->pageForPagination('Income');
$page1 = $this->pageForPagination('Expense');
public $paginate = array(
    'Income' => array (
            'order'=>array('income_id'=>'ASC'),
            'limit'=>10,
            'page' => $page,
            'recursive'=>0  
    ),
    'Expense' => array (
            'order'=>array('expense_id'=>'ASC'),
            'limit'=>10,
            'page' => $page1,
            'recursive'=>0,

    ));
} else if ($this->request->params['named']['model'] == 'Income') {
$page = $this->pageForPagination('Income');
public $paginate = array(
    'Income' => array (
            'order'=>array('income_id'=>'ASC'),
            'limit'=>10,
            'page' => $page,
            'recursive'=>0  

));
} else if ($this->request->params['named']['model'] == 'Expense') {
$page1 = $this->pageForPagination('Expense');
public $paginate = array(
    'Expense' => array (
            'order'=>array('income_id'=>'ASC'),
            'limit'=>10,
            'page' => $page1,
            'recursive'=>0  

  ));
```

Step 4: Now call the paging element in your student view

```
<?php echo $this->element('paging', array('model' => 'Income'));?>
 <?php echo $this->element('paging', array('model' => 'Expense'));?>
```

Note: Please take care of brackets and semicolon.......and sorry to be late but will help others...Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

I think if you use two different iframes to load different URLs for pagination, you can handle this. 
OR you have to call ajax functions to paginate 2 models in one page without reloading the page....